# Access constant or variables from inside a function to in `viewdidload` to save in firebase swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to access constant or variables which are defined inside a function for example i have defined a constant inside a `didselectrow` function now when i select a row the value of constant get printed in console but now i want to save that value in `firebase` so when i call that value in `button` it is undefined why? what should i do that??

here is the code i have written in `button` the constant `countryGroup` is undefined. because i have defined it in `didselectrow`

**button**

```
 @IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: Any) {
 ref.child("user_registration").child(UserID!).setValue(["username": fullName.text, "email": emailTextField.text, "contact": numberText.text, "city": myCity.text, "state": countryText.text, "country": country])
}
```

**didselectrow**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView == tableViewB {

        let   selectedData = dropDownList[indexPath.row]

        buttonB.setTitle(selectedData, for: .normal)


        self.tableViewB.isHidden = true
        self.flag = 1

        let indexPath = tableViewB.indexPathForSelectedRow

        let currentCell = tableViewB.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
        let country = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
        print("\(country)")
    }
```

Comment: because that becomes a local variable not an instance variable.Define variable outside function.

Comment: what should i do so i can retrieve in firebase?

Comment: declare let selectedData:Int? Outside table function and within function just use -: selectedData = dropDownList[indexPath.row]

Comment: error at  `selectedData = dropDownList[indexPath.row]` `can not aasign the value of 'String ' to int`

Comment: because your array is of string type declare variable like this-: let selectedData: String?

Comment: declared but still use of unresolved identifier

Comment: Can you show updated code please.

Comment: ok dear i m doing that

Comment: This is a wild guess but maybe your `firebase` library uses key value coding . If so your class should inherit from NSObject for this to work. Regular Swift classes don't support it.

Comment: @TusharSharma Instead of defining let country = currentCell.textLabel!.text! in didselectrow i have defined a global variable var country = String? and set country = currentCell.textLabel!.text!

Comment: @Kamil.S may be but i resolved the issue thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining `let country = currentCell.textLabel!.text!` in `didselectrow` i have defined a global variable `var country = String?` and set `country = currentCell.textLabel!.text!`